# What are some use cases for atomic GETSET operation?

Tags: redis, atomic, database, nosql

I've been reading the documentation for Redis, [the example they have for GETSET is just "Hello World"](http://redis.io/commands/getset). I can't think of a specific case where I could use GETSET but it wouldn't be better handled by pushing or inserting into a list. What are some specific use cases for when an old value has to be retrieved atomically but not stored as well?

Comment: Could you add a link to the documentation that you're referring to in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc presents the atomic counter get and reset pattern but generally this command is suitable for any situation where you have a (string) value that you want to set while getting the previous value atomically. Personally, I haven't seen the command used extensively so I can't testify about other use cases.

The list approach can be used for a similar effect, but when you pop an element you change the list itself - the old value is no longer there and there could be other operations (unless you use MULTI/EXEC) executed before you push the new value.

Comment: In real world scenarios GETSET can be used as part of manual expire management SETNX based locks (http://redis.io/commands/setnx) or for reset counters with arbitrary time step. For example, from your last visit occurred X events. So you can catch counter value and reset it in one command.